# Android - Open play store for update doesn't ask to update

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play, version, updates

I have inserted some code in my app to check if there is a new version avaliable.

In case there is one, the user get a dialog asking if he want to update.

Everything is working fine, but the problem is that even if the play store is showing that the current version avaliable is 1.1, and the users has the version 1.0, it still ask to "launch" or "uninstall" the app, and doesn t show any update button.

This is problematic because the user will keep recieving the update dialog and will be redirected to a page that isn t showing any updated version.

here is my code:

```
if (!lastVersion.equals(actualVersion)){

                DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which){
                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                            //Yes button clicked
                            try {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.xxx.yyy"));
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xxx.yyy")));
                            }
                            break;

                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                            //No button clicked
                            if (force_update){
                                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                };
```

Comment: Is this also true if you go back and click the button once again? Because I know that very often the App Page in the market App can be cached, so to see the update version you need to back out and re-enter the App page for it to fetch a the new version? Also out of curiosity, how are you checking for a new version? Your own API or by parsing/asking the marketplace?

Comment: @NicklasGnejsEriksson Hey, thank you for taking the time to help me.
So, even if I close everything, click back and go again on it, still the same problem. I have tried all I can think about.

As for the version checking I've done something very simple.

I have a php file on my server rendering a json object containing the last version, a force_update variable, a message and some other parameter I would like to manage without update needed.

Then I retrieve this object from my app and compare the version string to the app version. If it's equal, do nothing, else, show dialog.

Comment: If it is not the caching then I am not sure what it could be actually. Have you tried to do a search instead with "search?q=pname:yourpackage" and then entering the App page manually to see if it has the Update? Or if you just do the full check manually in the Play Store? Ah oki, your own API, I see. :) Sorry I can't be of much help^^ Good luck :)

Comment: I have found the problem, I will answer my own question :)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my own problem.

In fact, as I had modified my app and tested it on the phone I was trying to get the update proposal on, I guess something, maybe an apk signature, was irrevelant for the apk published on the play store.

I tried to then install the apk version 1.0 from the store, and then, the play store shown me the update button.

Comment: So you the version you tested with was not from the Market? Yeah that would probably explain it, since you cannot update from a non-market version to a market-version of the App^^ Good luck!

Comment: @NicklasGnejsEriksson Yes exactly, this was my first android app update, so I ll know for the next time :)

Comment: can you give me the code, because i am facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

We can get last version using this request https://androidquery.appspot.com/api/market?app=com.instagram.android

But if our app is blocked we get 500 error